# template argument deduction/substitution failed, when using std::function and std::bind

Tags: c++, templates, bind, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I have a compile error when using std::function in a templated member function, the following code is a simple example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
using std::function;
using std::bind;
using std::shared_ptr;

class Test {
public:
     template <typename T>
     void setCallback(function<void (T, int)> cb); 
};

template <typename T>
void Test::setCallback(function<void (T, int)> cb)
{
    // do nothing
}

class TestA {
public:
    void testa(int a, int b) {   }
};


int main()
{
    TestA testA;
    Test test;
    test.setCallback(bind(&TestA::testa, &testA, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    return 0;
}
```

And come with the following compile error:

> testtemplate.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> testtemplate.cpp:29:92: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘Test::setCallback(std::_Bind_helper)(int, int),
>   TestA, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const
>   std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type)’
>
> testtemplate.cpp:29:92: note: candidate is: testtemplate.cpp:10:7:
>   note: template void Test::setCallback(std::function)
>
> testtemplate.cpp:10:7: note:   template argument
>   deduction/substitution failed:
>
> testtemplate.cpp:29:92: note:   ‘std::_Bind(TestA*, std::_Placeholder<1>,
>   std::_Placeholder<2>)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function’

I'm using C++11 and g++ 4.7

Comment: Say `test.setCallback<int>(bind...)`. The result of `bind` is not an `std::function`, so there's no argument deduction.

Comment: Please tell me how you think the compiler could possibly figure out what to deduce `T` to.

Comment: @Xeo I'm a freshman in template, i don't know how the dedece T work.some material help?

Comment: @user1679133: In general, when `std::function` is a parameter, you have to spell out the type fully unless you pass a `std::function`.

Comment: Lambdas are a better choice over `std::bind`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To figure out the problem let separate statements:

```
auto f = bind(&TestA::testa, &testA, _1, _2); // OK
test.setCallback(f);                          // <<--- Error is here
```

`setCallback` needs to know type of `T` and it can't deduce it from `f`, so give it a type

```
test.setCallback<TYPE>(f); // TYPE: int, float, a class, ...
```

Comment: template is so hard, I use a whole afternoon to deal with this problem,and finally, i can't solve, thanks for your explanation. by the way, can you give me some advices on learing template

Comment: @user1679133: Program and practice everyday, It's the only way to learn programming concepts. The way we all did. And read Q&A from Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can make type deduction work with some variant of:

```
template<typename CALLBACK>
void setCallback(CALLBACK cb) {
  typedef CALLBACK::first_argument_type T;
  static_assert(is_same_type<CALLBACK,function<void(T,int)>>::value);
  ...
}
```

This way CALLBACK can be determined by looking at the argument.  It might get into trouble if bind doesn't actually return a std::function but rather something that can be cast as one.  I'm not sure.