# Including header file in .cpp causes nasty error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a header file called `transaction_gen.h` and a corresponding cpp file called `transaction_gen.cpp`.

Here is what I have in `transaction_gen.h`

```
#ifndef BITCOIN_TEST_GEN_TRANSACTION_GEN_H
#define BITCOIN_TEST_GEN_TRANSACTION_GEN_H

#include <rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h>
#include <rapidcheck/Gen.h>
#include "primitives/transaction.h" 
#include "script/script.h"
#include "amount.h"
#include "test/gen/script_gen.h"
#include "test/gen/crypto_gen.h"

namespace rc {

  template<>
  struct Arbitrary<COutPoint> {
    static Gen<COutPoint> arbitrary() { 
      return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<uint256>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<uint256, uint32_t> outPointPrimitives) {
          uint32_t nIn; 
          uint256 nHashIn; 
          std::tie(nHashIn, nIn) = outPointPrimitives;
          return COutPoint(nHashIn, nIn);
          });
    };
  };


  template<> 
  struct Arbitrary<CTxIn> { 
    static Gen<CTxIn> arbitrary() { 
      return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<COutPoint>(), gen::arbitrary<CScript>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<COutPoint, CScript, uint32_t> txInPrimitives) { 
        COutPoint outpoint; 
        CScript script;
        uint32_t sequence; 
        std::tie(outpoint,script,sequence) = txInPrimitives; 
        return CTxIn(outpoint,script,sequence); 
      });
    };
  };
  /** Generates one or more inputs */ 
  Gen<std::vector<CTxIn>> oneOrMoreInputs();


  template<>
  struct Arbitrary<CAmount> {
    static Gen<CAmount> arbitrary() {
      //why doesn't this generator call work? It seems to cause an infinite loop. 
      //return gen::arbitrary<int64_t>();
      return gen::inRange(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min(),std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
    };
  }; 

  template<>
  struct Arbitrary<CTxOut> { 
    static Gen<CTxOut> arbitrary() { 
      return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<CAmount>(), gen::arbitrary<CScript>()), [](std::tuple<CAmount, CScript> txOutPrimitives) {
        CAmount amount;  
        CScript script;
        std::tie(amount,script) = txOutPrimitives;
        return CTxOut(amount,script);
      });
    };
  };
```

and here is what I have in the corresponding cpp file

```
#include <rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h>
#include <rapidcheck/Gen.h>

#include "primitives/transaction.h" 
#include "script/script.h"
#include "amount.h"

#include "test/gen/transaction_gen.h"

namespace rc { 

  /** Generates one or more inputs */ 
  Gen<std::vector<CTxIn>> oneOrMoreInputs() {
    return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxIn>>(), [](std::vector<CTxIn> vin) {
      return vin.size() > 0;      
    });
  }

  /** Generates one or more outputs */ 
  Gen<std::vector<CTxOut>> oneOrMoreOutputs() { 
    return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxOut>>(), [](std::vector<CTxOut> vout) {
      return vout.size() > 0;      
    });
  }

}
```

and this will compile fine when I build my program.

However, since I want to be using functionality located in `transaction_gen.h` I obviously want to include it in my program. However, when I include it I get a long nasty error message:

```
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~/.../src/test$ make
make -C .. bitcoin_test
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/chris/dev/bitcoin/src'
  CXX      test/test_test_bitcoin-transaction_properties.o
  CXX      test/gen/test_test_bitcoin-transaction_gen.o
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CKey> rc::Arbitrary<CKey>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:19:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(rc::Arbitrary<CKey>::arbitrary()::<lambda(int)>)’
       });
        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note: candidate: template<class T, class Mapper> rc::Gen<typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>::type> rc::gen::map(rc::Gen<T>, Mapper&&)
 Gen<Decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>> map(Gen<T> gen,
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:19:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
       });
        ^
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<std::vector<unsigned char, secure_allocator<unsigned char> > > rc::Arbitrary<std::vector<unsigned char, secure_allocator<unsigned char> > >::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:29:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(rc::Arbitrary<std::vector<unsigned char, secure_allocator<unsigned char> > >::arbitrary()::<lambda(CKey)>)’
       });
        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note: candidate: template<class T, class Mapper> rc::Gen<typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>::type> rc::gen::map(rc::Gen<T>, Mapper&&)
 Gen<Decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>> map(Gen<T> gen,
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:29:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
       });
        ^
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CPubKey> rc::Arbitrary<CPubKey>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:39:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(rc::Arbitrary<CPubKey>::arbitrary()::<lambda(CKey)>)’
       });
        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note: candidate: template<class T, class Mapper> rc::Gen<typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>::type> rc::gen::map(rc::Gen<T>, Mapper&&)
 Gen<Decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>> map(Gen<T> gen,
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:39:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
       });
        ^
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<uint256> rc::Arbitrary<uint256>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:49:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(rc::Arbitrary<uint256>::arbitrary()::<lambda(int)>)’
       }); 
        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:74:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note: candidate: template<class T, class Mapper> rc::Gen<typename std::decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>::type> rc::gen::map(rc::Gen<T>, Mapper&&)
 Gen<Decay<typename std::result_of<Mapper(T)>::type>> map(Gen<T> gen,
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.hpp:15:54: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:49:8: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
       }); 
        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct rc::Arbitrary<std::vector<unsigned char> >’:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:17:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary() [with T = std::vector<unsigned char>]’
./test/gen/script_gen.h:13:66:   required from here
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:22:62: error: incomplete type ‘rc::gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<std::vector<unsigned char> >’ used in nested name specifier
   static decltype(gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                                              ^
In file included from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/script_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CScript> rc::Arbitrary<CScript>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/script_gen.h:13:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘arbitrary()’
       return gen::map(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<unsigned char>>(), [](std::vector<unsigned char> script) {
                                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note: candidate: template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary()
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:0:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<COutPoint> rc::Arbitrary<COutPoint>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:17:23: error: ‘tuple’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
       return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<uint256>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<uint256, uint32_t> outPointPrimitives) {
                       ^
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:17:23: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:62,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Seq.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Shrinkable.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:83:11: note:   ‘std::tuple’
     class tuple;
           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct rc::Arbitrary<unsigned int>’:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:17:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary() [with T = unsigned int]’
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:17:86:   required from here
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:22:62: error: incomplete type ‘rc::gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<unsigned int>’ used in nested name specifier
   static decltype(gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                                              ^
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:0:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:17:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘arbitrary()’
       return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<uint256>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<uint256, uint32_t> outPointPrimitives) {
                                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note: candidate: template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary()
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:0:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CTxIn> rc::Arbitrary<CTxIn>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:30:23: error: ‘tuple’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
       return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<COutPoint>(), gen::arbitrary<CScript>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<COutPoint, CScript, uint32_t> txInPrimitives) { 
                       ^
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:30:23: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:62,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Seq.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Shrinkable.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:83:11: note:   ‘std::tuple’
     class tuple;
           ^
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:0:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:30:115: error: no matching function for call to ‘arbitrary()’
       return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<COutPoint>(), gen::arbitrary<CScript>(), gen::arbitrary<uint32_t>()), [](std::tuple<COutPoint, CScript, uint32_t> txInPrimitives) { 
                                                                                                                   ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note: candidate: template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary()
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h: In substitution of ‘template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary() [with T = unsigned int]’:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:30:115:   required from here
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:17:33: error: ‘arbitrary’ is not a member of ‘rc::Arbitrary<unsigned int>’
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary();
                                 ^
In file included from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:0:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<long int> rc::Arbitrary<long int>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:48:14: error: ‘inRange’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
       return gen::inRange(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min(),std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
              ^
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CTxOut> rc::Arbitrary<CTxOut>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:55:23: error: ‘tuple’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
       return gen::map(gen::tuple(gen::arbitrary<CAmount>(), gen::arbitrary<CScript>()), [](std::tuple<CAmount, CScript> txOutPrimitives) {
                       ^
./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:55:23: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:62,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Seq.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Shrinkable.h:3,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/Gen.h:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:3,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:83:11: note:   ‘std::tuple’
     class tuple;
           ^
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp: In function ‘rc::Gen<std::vector<CTxIn> > rc::oneOrMoreInputs()’:
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:14:12: error: ‘suchThat’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
     return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxIn>>(), [](std::vector<CTxIn> vin) {
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct rc::Arbitrary<std::vector<CTxIn> >’:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:17:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary() [with T = std::vector<CTxIn>]’
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:14:61:   required from here
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:22:62: error: incomplete type ‘rc::gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<std::vector<CTxIn> >’ used in nested name specifier
   static decltype(gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                                              ^
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:14:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘arbitrary()’
     return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxIn>>(), [](std::vector<CTxIn> vin) {
                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note: candidate: template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary()
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp: In function ‘rc::Gen<std::vector<CTxOut> > rc::oneOrMoreOutputs()’:
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:21:12: error: ‘suchThat’ is not a member of ‘rc::gen’
     return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxOut>>(), [](std::vector<CTxOut> vout) {
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct rc::Arbitrary<std::vector<CTxOut> >’:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:17:33:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary() [with T = std::vector<CTxOut>]’
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:21:62:   required from here
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:22:62: error: incomplete type ‘rc::gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<std::vector<CTxOut> >’ used in nested name specifier
   static decltype(gen::detail::DefaultArbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                                              ^
test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:21:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘arbitrary()’
     return gen::suchThat(gen::arbitrary<std::vector<CTxOut>>(), [](std::vector<CTxOut> vout) {
                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h:22:0,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note: candidate: template<class T> decltype (rc::Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) rc::gen::arbitrary()
 decltype(Arbitrary<T>::arbitrary()) arbitrary() {
                                     ^
/usr/local/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp:13:37: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
make[1]: *** [test/gen/test_test_bitcoin-transaction_gen.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chris/dev/bitcoin/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

and I'm not really sure why this is happening. It almost seems like when I include `transaction_gen.h` it erases all other header files I had included, this the problems like

```
In file included from ./test/gen/script_gen.h:6:0,
                 from ./test/gen/transaction_gen.h:9,
                 from test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp:8:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h: In static member function ‘static rc::Gen<CKey> rc::Arbitrary<CKey>::arbitrary()’:
./test/gen/crypto_gen.h:19:8: error: no matching function for call to ‘map(rc::Arbitrary<CKey>::arbitrary()::<lambda(int)>)’
       });
```

because this obviously is included properly when I exclude `transaction_gen.h`. Where am I going wrong here? I feel like this is a pretty simple fix but I've spent a couple hours on it now to avail :/

EDIT: I've pushed this up to github

Here is [transaction_gen.h](https://github.com/Christewart/bitcoin/blob/rapidcheck_template_error/src/test/gen/transaction_gen.h)

Here is [transaction_gen.cpp](https://github.com/Christewart/bitcoin/blob/rapidcheck_template_error/src/test/gen/transaction_gen.cpp)

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to diagnose without a short complete example of the issue.  Try narrowing your code down and editing it into the question.  You may have a circular include or some sort of shadowing issue if those functions actually exist and take the parameters you're passing.

Comment: Looking at your errors / notes, I can guess that some templates are not getting instantiated when you comment out `#include ...transaction_gen.h`. But the traits / template code is getting executed when you include your `.h` file. If you are sure of the template / trait code, then focus on its use in your `.h` file. If not, you may want to look at the template / traits code you're attempting to use.

Comment: The issue seems to be an issue in template deduction in Arbitrary.h. From the error message, looks to be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542530/template-argument-deduction-substitution-failed-when-using-stdfunction-and-st

Comment: @levengli if you are interested in looking at the implementation of Arbitrary, i cannot tell for myself what is wrong: https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck/blob/master/include/rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.hpp

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've added more code to the OP to try and help.

Comment: Except for precompiled header, the corresponding header file should always be the first on in the source file. By doing so, you ensure that your header file do include all required files. **It is a very bad idea to put it last as you have done** as it won't help you at all identifying missing includes in the corresponding header file.

Comment: @Phil1970 Didn't realize this, I applied your fix, but it didn't change anything else. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove these lines from transaction_gen.cpp:

```
#include <rapidcheck/gen/Arbitrary.h>
#include <rapidcheck/Gen.h>

#include "primitives/transaction.h" 
#include "script/script.h"
#include "amount.h"
```

Keep this #include line only:

```
#include "test/gen/transaction_gen.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `transaction_gen.h` is missing a `#endif` at the end of the file.

Comment: Isn't it right here? https://github.com/Christewart/bitcoin/blob/rapidcheck_template_error/src/test/gen/transaction_gen.h#L103

Comment: Indeed it is, but it isn't in the code in your question. I think you will experience that it is easier to get answers if you post a mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Include these in your cpp file also

```
#include "test/gen/script_gen.h"
#include "test/gen/crypto_gen.h"
```