# std::function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I have created a example my current problem.
I want to be able to able to call the following function without specifying the template type since the compiler should be able to find out the type:

```
template<typename T, class Iterable>
void foreach1(std::function<void(T&)> action, Iterable& iterable) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    for (auto& data : iterable)
        action(data);
}
```

If i call the function this way:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach1([](int& data) {
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}, a);
```

I get an error. I know that i could fix the problem by replacing *std::function* with a template the following way:

```
template<class Action, class Iterable>
void foreach2(Action action, Iterable& iterable) {
//std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; // no access to T
for (auto& data : iterable)
    action(data);
}
```

But by doing that i lose access to the type *T*.
Is there a way of keeping access to the type *T* and be able to use template argument deduction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failure to deduce template argument std::function from lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326206/failure-to-deduce-template-argument-stdfunction-from-lambda-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implicit conversions are not allowed when passing arguments to parameters whose types depend on deduced template parameters.

I suggest using the second option:

```
template<class Action, class Iterable>
void foreach2(Action action, Iterable& iterable)
```

And to determine `T`, start with making a `std::function` out of `action`:

```
std::function(action)
```

Then write a template to get the type of the parameter of a `std::function`:

```
template <typename T> struct std_func_param {};
template <typename R, typename T> struct std_func_param<std::function<R(T)>> {using type = T;};
template <typename T> using std_func_param_t = typename std_func_param<T>::type;
```

Use it like this:

```
using T = std_func_param_t<decltype(std::function(action))>;
```

Comment: Is there a runtime cost in converting a lambda to a std::function? I have read in some places not to use std::function in most cases. Is this one case where you have to use it?

Comment: @Dolfos There might be a runtime cost, but in this case `std::function(action)` is only used inside of `decltype()`, which means it's not evaluated. No actual `std::function` is constructed.

Comment: How come there might be a runtime cost when it's not evaluated?

Comment: @Dolfos I mean there would probably be a runtime cost if `std::function(action)` was evaluated. Since it's not, there is no extra cost.

Comment: Does the compiler optimize the construction of std::function away because decltype() does not count as "using" the variable?

Comment: @Dolfos Yes, it's required to.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.