How to expand function template parameters package in std::function as the function's argument?
This question is an extension of another question from a decade ago:
#include<functional>
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
struct Caller
{
    static void Call(std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>);
};
template <typename ReturnType, typename...ArgumentTypes>
void Call(std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>f);
int main()
{
    Caller<void>::Call([]() {});//Well-formed
    Call<void>({[]() {}});//Well-formed
    Call<void>([]() {});//Ill-formed
}

The code provides three methods to expand the template parameter package in the std::function signature. The first two have been tested as well-formed and can be compiled; the last is the same as the old question and is thus ill-formed. The question is, in what way do the first two methods bypass the problem that causes compilation failure in the original problem and the last method?

I can't say why Call<void>({[]() {}});//Well-formed compiles but Call<void>([]() {});//Ill-formed doesn't because of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326206/failure-to-deduce-template-argument-stdfunction-from-lambda-function

For struct Caller, all template arguments are passed (just void and empty pack), lambda can be converted to std::function<void()>.

@NathanOliver -- that reference you provided is based on "A lambda won't deduce the template parameters of a std::function because they are unrelated types", which is wrong. std::function can deduce return and argument types from lambda as long as they are not templates (auto)

@Gene It can do so with std::function foo = lambda because of CTAD.  It doesn't work if the std::function is getting its parameters deduced from a function parameter: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aceb8468800936c

@NathanOliver -- I'm not saying that the deduction in that particular case should not fail, I'm saying the answer in that link is wrong.

@Gene I'll haver to disagree with you on that.

For struct Caller, all template arguments are passed (just void and empty pack) as there are no partial CTAD. Lambda can be converted to std::function<void()>, so it is ok.
For function template Call, provided argument are just the first ones, deduction might still happens.
One way to stop possible deduction is to store in intermediate variable:
auto call = Call<void>; // void (*)()
call([](){}); // OK

Demo
lambda are not std::function so cannot be deduced as std::function<Ret(Args...)>, so third method fails.
For the second, the extra {..} also stops deduction:
See template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts #7 for more details:

The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not std::initializer_list, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or a reference to an array}}:


Since {..} has no type shouldn't type deduction for Args... fail?

I originally thought the same about {..} case, but then it only works with empty parameter pack. If you change the argument to say int, Call<void>({[](int) {}}); fails, while Call<void>(std::function([](int) {})); succeeds.

I think the reason for the observed behavior is that in all of those cases there is no deduction of function arguments. The explicitly specialized Call<void> is expanded as having empty pack, meaning only int(void) lambda can possibly match. When using std::function cast, both return type and parameter packs are deduced.

Since the explanation of the second case has been crossed out of this answer, what is the correct explanation?

@埃博拉酱: I had to investigate a little to found the correct answer.
